# Network is unreachable when I clone my bitbucket repo in private AWS instance

Tags: linux, git, amazon-web-services, bitbucket, port

I am trying to clone my bitbucket repository into my private AWS instance but it is giving me a 'network is unreachable' error.

I have successfully established a connection to the private instance using bastion host and I'm able to access it but when I'm trying to git clone my repository it is just timing out with the error:

ssh: connect to host altssh.bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Are you able to ping the destination from your current location?

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to clone git repos from other servers, if yes, then it can be because of Security Group rule between the instance and Git is not in place or the Firewalld service running at the OS level

You can use telnet command to troubleshoot the issue further from the instance you are trying to clone git repo

`telnet altssh.bitbucket.org  443`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick reply.
It was an issue with my outbound rules in my security group.
It's working fine now.

Thanks